# Gradle (Java) cannot find symbol for class in subdirectory of package

Tags: java, android, gradle

It's been some years since I have programmed Java and I am having trouble with resolving a build issue with not finding a symbol for a class in the same package directory structure.

```
package com.A.B.C; 
public class Manager {
...
}
```

The following class is attempting to reference `Manager`. Note the package declarations for both classes.

```
package com.A.B;
import com.A.B.C.Manager; // I have also tried omitting this import statement; same result 
public class MyApp extends Application {                                                               
...
  @Override                                                                                            
  public void onCreate() {
...
    registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(Manager); // cannot find symbol SessionManager
  }
...
}
```

I am importing `com.A.B.C.Manager` in other source files and able to reference `Manager` there but, for this source file, Gradle cannot resolve the symbol.

What am I missing? (This is an Android project by the way, in case that is relevant.)

In advance, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That **Manager** class have to implement **Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks** like this:

```
package com.A.B.C; 
public class Manager implements Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks{
    ...
}
```

Also, I guess you missed the **new** while calling *registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks()* :

```
registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Manager());
```

Comment: Thank you @Sujal Kumar. Your suggestion to `new Manager()` was what I was missing.

Comment: @eppineda Glad to help. If you found the answer useful, please mark it with that green tick so it shows the question as solved :)